# Node-Red Dashboard Slider value

Tags: node.js, dashboard, node-red

Since I'm new and struggling with the Dashboard UI for Node Red, I'm asking the question.

How do I pass a Value of a Slider and a Switch into a Function to work with them.
msg.payload doesn't work.

I'm sorry, I know that it is probably a pretty easy question. Just not used to programming with JS.

Thanks in advance

Thats my current code of the function just for testing:
in the future i want to use the value of a slider to get passed by if the switch is true

```
if(msg.payload === true)
{
    return 20;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `msg.payload` doesn't work? All the UI nodes output values in `msg.payload`. Edit the question to include the code you have tried and explain what errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The `msg.payload` from a slider node will be a numeric value so comparing it to `true` will always return `false`.

As for a swtich it will set the `msg.payload` to true or false so you don't need to compare this to anything, just use `msg.payload` as the whole condition e.g.

```
if (msg.payload) {
  ...
}
```

Also you can not return a raw value from a function node, it needs to be a msg object, with at least a `payload` field e.g.

```
if(msg.payload)
{
  return { payload: 20};
}
```

Comment: So I can't use the value of the slider as a return

Comment: Function nodes must return a `msg` object, so any value you want to return must be wrapped in an object with the value set as the `msg.payload`